# How to start stopped couchbase cluster with docker

Tags: docker, couchbase

I am trying to create a local couchbase cluster using docker on my ubuntu laptop.
I am following https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.1/install/docker-deploy-multi-node-cluster.html.

I am able to create cluster and do all the couchbase operations.

However after stopping the containers I am trying to start them using

```
docker container start
```

I have started all 3 containers one by one.

If I run the following commands

```
docker logs db1
docker logs db2
docker logs db3
```

I can see proper logs.

However when I am trying to access the UI

```
curl http://localhsot:8091
```

I see

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Please advice how to create, start, stop couchbase cluster using docker and retain data from a stopped container.

Comment: You should be able to start the stopped container and able to access the url. If you need to retain the data, use volumes `-v` option to mount volume. If you look at the docker file for couchbase (last line), you can mount the volume.

Comment: hi Bala thanks for your quick response. could you please share any doc link ?

Comment: Link to docker volume https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ and link to couchbase docker file https://github.com/couchbase/docker/blob/78cbcaa2c90ce4c975299e7cbfdce146a7bab081/community/couchbase-server/6.6.0/Dockerfile

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue in my test project. However, I followed the docs that you have shared. Configure cluster http://x.x.x.x:8091 then stop the container one by one and started them again and able to login  http://x.x.x.x:8091. 

Output of curl command:

curl http://x.x.x.x:8091



<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head><body><h1>Moved Permanently</h1><p>The document has moved <a href="http://x.x.x.x:8091/ui/index.html>here</a>.</p></body></html>

Comment: Mahboob could you please tell me how are you starting the 3 stopped container after restart of your machine ?